# В чем преимущества AndroidStudio над eclipse?

Tags: android-studio, eclipse, android

В чем преимущества AndroidStudio над eclipse? Просто стало очень интересно мнение других людей, кто что рекомендует.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Да ну, было же уже! http://hashcode.ru/questions/216832/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-ide-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-android-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java  
Все, что было сказано про Intellij IDEA, применимо и к Android Studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- + зарекомендовано intellij idea и продвигается google
- + поддержка gradle
- + магия
- - beta (на 09.2015 уже давно не бета)

плагины, подсветки, настройки и остальные темы холивара оставлю, так как относительно кривизны рук можно или настроить эклипс и боготворить его, или не освоить студию

Comment: Мне вот больше интересно, в чем преимущество AndroidStudio над IntellijIdea (помимо легковесности, хотя комьюнити эдишн тоже не особо тяжелая).

Comment: Поддержка gradle и вообще полностью заточена под андроид.

Comment: @Gorets, насколько мне известно, то IDEA тоже поддерживает gradle. Но да, я сам перешел на студию, потому что она точится дополнительно только под андроид уже самим гуглом, а все плюхи, которые есть в IDEA, она и так вбирает в себя.

Comment: Что-то я этой заточенности, видимо, не оценил, про gradle написали выше. Так и не понял плюсов, кроме магии. Помню, при разработке с libgdx AS у меня подавилась, а IDEA всё скушала. После этого, правда, даже не пытался перейти, т.к. каких-либо неудобств не особо заметил :)

Comment: То, что пишет google для AS попадает и в IDEA CE почти сразу, у них активный обмен кодом в обе стороны. Отличие AS в некоторых мастерах-помошниках создания всяких спицефических анроидных плюшек и в отсутствии из коробки многих плагинов, не нужных в андроид-разработке (при желании их можно доустановить из репозитория)